# External monitor goes black randomly

Tags: windows-10, laptop, display, dell-inspiron

Any external monitor where I connect laptop goes randomly going black. First only blinking. Now barely come online.

- Dell Inspiron 7577
- Windows 10 64bit
- Integrated GPU: Intel HD Graphics 630
- Dedicated GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti
- Connection: HDMI (laptop)-HDMI (monitor 1 HP 24uh), HDMI-VGA (monitor 2). Cables both less than 1m long.

Was working correctly before. Didn't change anything manually until this started happening.

- Tried another monitor (2). Exactly same issue. Even used a different cable.
- Other laptop works with both monitors and cables. This proves problem is in this laptop.
- Physically moving the adaptor or moving the laptop doesn't seem to do anything. Appears to be software.
- Have latest Windows updates.
- Have tried rebooting.
- Have removed battery, and shut down computer.
- Tried extend, duplicate, using monitor as single monitor
- Disable both GPUs and problem persists.
- Uninstalled both cards and removed drivers. Problem persists, so it appears it's not either GPU's fault either.
- Have latest HD 630 drivers. Tried first from Dell then from Intel.
- If I extend displays, it's as if it was there. I can click on things. Just the monitor is black.
- Ran 30min test on Dells support website, passed every test.
- BIOS has latest Dell's update.
- Refresh rate set in Advanced display settings is within the monitors refresh rate.
- Formatted PC. Clean install, all files deleted.

Other possibilities:

- EM interference;
- Faulty PSU.

No idea what else to try.

Comment: Run the Dell Driver Updater and be sure to include BIOS in the updates. Do all that apply to your computer

Comment: @John No change

Comment: Did you ever sort this out?  I'm getting a similar issue